# ValueError: Cannot assign "4749890231992320L": "Student.user" must be a "User" instance. (Django + custom models)

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm having issues with using `Model.objects.get` with a custom model that includes a standard Django user as one of the fields. Here are the basic attributes:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School)
    isHead = models.BooleanField()
```

I made a new `School`, `User`, and `Student`, and saved them all without problem. So I typed the following into a `manage.py shell`, where `new` is the variable for the `User` object:

```
Student.objects.get(user = new)
```

Then, I get the error:

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "5312840185413632L": "Student.user" must be a "User" instance.
```

I've done some research, and I understand the above to mean that I'm passing something that is *not* a `User` object as the parameter. However, I've defined

```
new = User(username="new user")
```

so I can't figure out what I'm doing incorrectly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If it helps, I'm working within Eclipse, which is new to me, although Django/python is not.

EDIT: Here is my the full code for the custom classes:

```
class School(models.Model):
    def level(self):
        return get_max_triangle_num_less_than(self.rep / SCHOOL_REP_LEVEL_MODIFIER)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    # Rep could also be a DecimalField (needs max_digits and decimal_places specified)
    rep = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    num_students = models.IntegerField(default = 0)

    def __init__(self, name, *args, **kwargs):
        models.Model.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.name + ", " + str(self.num_students) + " students"

class Student(models.Model):

    def level(self):
        return get_max_triangle_num_less_than(self.rep / STUDENT_REP_LEVEL_MODIFIER)

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School)
    isHead = models.BooleanField()

    referral_code = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    referred_by = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)

    rep = models.IntegerField(default = 0)

    def __init__(self, user, school, referred_by = None, *args, **kwargs):
        models.Model.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.user = user
        self.school = school
        if referred_by:
            self.referred_by = referred_by

        # This automatically creates a custom string of letters/numbers -- I thought it was 
        #  the easiest way to make a custom "referral code" which can be used to link a 
        #  registration to the referrer
        self.referral_code = str(uuid.uuid4())

        self.school.num_students += 1

    def __str__(self):
        something = str(self.user.username)
        if self.isHead:
            something += ", Head at "
        else:
            something += ", at "
        something += self.school.name + ", " + str(self.rep) + " rep points"
        return something
```

And here is what I type into the shell + traceback:

```
>>> from spudmart.campusrep.models import User, School, Student
>>> usr = User(username="user")
>>> usr.save()
>>> sch = School(name = "school")
>>> sch.save()
>>> stu = Student(user = usr, school = sch)
>>> stu.save()
>>> Student.objects.get(user = usr)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/Lucy/Code/Git/spudder/spudmart/src/django/db/models/manager.py", line 132, in get
    return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Lucy/Code/Git/spudder/spudmart/src/django/db/models/query.py", line 346, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/Users/Lucy/Code/Git/spudder/spudmart/src/django/db/models/query.py", line 82, in __len__
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/Users/Lucy/Code/Git/spudder/spudmart/src/django/db/models/query.py", line 288, in iterator
    obj = model(*row[index_start:aggregate_start], **{'__entity_exists': True})
  File "/Users/Lucy/Code/Git/spudder/spudmart/src/spudmart/campusrep/models.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.user = user
  File "/Users/Lucy/Code/Git/spudder/spudmart/src/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 331, in __set__
    self.field.name, self.field.rel.to._meta.object_name))
ValueError: Cannot assign "4661929301770240L": "Student.user" must be a "User" instance.
```

Comment: it happens when I use other variable names... I just tried again with "usr_3" as the variable name and I got the same thing, slightly different number but otherwise the same error

Comment: Shows us your full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing something strange in models `__init__`, you need to move all this logic to `save()` method, have to be something like this:

```
class Student(models.Model):

def level(self):
    return get_max_triangle_num_less_than(self.rep / STUDENT_REP_LEVEL_MODIFIER)

user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
school = models.ForeignKey(School)
isHead = models.BooleanField()

referral_code = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
referred_by = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)

rep = models.IntegerField(default = 0)

def __str__(self):
    something = str(self.user.username)
    if self.isHead:
        something += ", Head at "
    else:
        something += ", at "
    something += self.school.name + ", " + str(self.rep) + " rep points"
    return something

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.pk is None:  # if this is new object (not update)
        self.school.num_students += 1
        self.referral_code = str(uuid.uuid4())
    instance = super(Student, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    return instance
```

Comment: Thanks for the `if self.pk is None` suggestion -- I wouldn't have caught that.

Answer (score 0):

After looking more closely at the traceback -- which I really should have done in the first place -- I tried commenting out code to override the `__init__` method. Lo and behold, it worked! Moral of the story: look more closely at the traceback before asking the internet. Thanks for your help though, everyone!